# SQL query ORDER BY two criteria not working correctly - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

So I'm new to SQL and I'm making this query that should print out the amounts of books written by the same author (grouped by AuthorID which is an integer), order them in decreasing order by the number of books, and after that order the AuthorIDs that have the same amount of books written in increasing order by the AuthorID itself (the integer). The problem is that it prints the AuthorIDs in decreasing order as well for some reason. Can anybody explain what am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT AuthorID, COUNT(*) 
       FROM book 
       GROUP BY AuthorID
       ORDER BY SUM(AuthorID) DESC, AuthorID ASC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the values you have in the SELECT to accomplish what you need. First order by COUNT(*) [your numbers of books] descending, then order by authorID ascending.

```
SELECT AuthorID, COUNT(*) 
       FROM book 
       GROUP BY AuthorID
       ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, AuthorID ASC;
```

You are introducing a totally new value, `SUM(AuthorID)` in your attempt, which is not what you want. If AuthorID is an INT value, that will spit out something totally different. You can probably see what the output is by testing it and then see where you went wrong.

```
SELECT AuthorID, SUM(AuthorID) AS test_col, COUNT(*) 
       FROM book 
       GROUP BY AuthorID
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! I will accept your answer ASAP!